# Why is dblink nested function rolling back?

Tags: postgresql, dblink

I assumed that dblink function were not rolledback, but in the use case below it is.

To summarize:
Function1 is a dblink call creating a table.
Function2 calls function1. Function2 is defined as RETURNS text missing the RETURNS statement.
On execution, function2 executes function1 then returns ERROR : Proccess reached end without return.

The table from dblink is not created.
Anyone has an explanation?

Function1:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function1 (_user text,_pwd text)
    RETURNS text
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
conn_string text;
BEGIN
conn_string := FORMAT('port = 5432 host=%1$s dbname=%2$s user=%3$s password=%4$s','host','db',_user,_mdp);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS foo;
EXECUTE FORMAT('CREATE TABLE foo AS
               (SELECT * FROM dblink(''%1$s'',''SELECT * FROM bar'') 
               AS t(id int, _text character varying, geom geometry(point)));',conn_string); 

RETURN 'foo created';

END;
$BODY$;
```

Function2 :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function2(_user text,_pwd text)
    RETURNS text
 
DECLARE

BEGIN

PERFORM function1(_user,_pwd);

END; -- END OF FUNCTION REACHED WITHOUT RETURN
$BODY$;
```

I understand that function2 is not a working function. What I don't is the fact that function1 (and the dblink within) is rollbacked and would like to understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following statement does not create a remote table in the database pointed to by the dblink, as the question seems to imply, but a local table `foo` initially populated with data from the remote.

```
EXECUTE FORMAT('CREATE TABLE foo AS
               (SELECT * FROM dblink(''%1$s'',''SELECT * FROM bar'') 
               AS t(id int, _text character varying, geom geometry(point)));',conn_string);
```

What is executed on the remote is a simple `SELECT`. The `CREATE TABLE` is executed locally as part of the current transaction, and it gets rolled back if the transaction fails later.

Comment: Indeed, you're right. I was confusing things with dblink_exec (in a totally different use case). Thanks for clearing it up.